# Is it possible to change gerund to infinitive in here?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Can I change the gerund in the following sentence: "**Being an activist** means using your voice" to the infinitive?
That is, the sentence would look like: "**To be an activist** means using your voice."

I only found out that we need a gerund after **mean** to have the right sense

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with two caveats:

1. You should also say *to use* to match the tense. (Native speakers sometimes fail to match these, but I believe we'd mostly all judge it to be an error if asked.)
2. The meaning is not quite the same. The gerund construction can have the meaning: "If you are an activist, you are expected to use your voice"; that is, it expresses a sense of duty. But the infinitive is a definition; it expresses an equivalence. I would say they're close enough and there's enough overlap in the pragmatic force of the statements that in real life a person might use either one for either meaning, but on reflection in an edited piece, they would probably restrict them to these uses.